# sliding menu on mobile web site

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

i'm working on a web mobile site and i'm having some problems that I really don't know how to solve them

I've added a sliding menu (like facebook's menu) but the problem is that my menu is longer than my page and when I scroll down I still get the menu but without the background color already defined

when I test it on a desktop navigator (chrome) it works perfectly but it I resize the window and make it smaller it invokes the same error

excuse me for my bad english & thanks for help ^^

html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="contactF" class="pages" data-add-back-btn="true" data-iconpos="notext">

    <div data-role="panel" id="menu" data-position="left" data-display="push">
        <ul id="menuList" data-role="listview" >
            <h3>Menu</h3>
            <li data-role="list-divider"><h6>r&eacute;seaux sociaux<h6/></li> 
            <li><a href="#" class="contentLink" id="contact_Facebook" data-add-back-btn="true">Facebook </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="contentLink" id="contact_Twitter">Twitter </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="contentLink" id="contact_Myspace">MySpace </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="header" id ="HeaderC" data-position="fixed">
    <!-- end of header -->

    <div data-role="content">
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    </div>

</div>
```

js:

```
$( document ).on("swipeleft swiperight", "#menu", function( e ) {
    if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open") {
      if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
        $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
      } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
        $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
      }
    }
    else if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) == "open"){
      $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "close" );
      $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "close" );
    }
  });
```

Comment: Create jsfiddle with containing an example. We can't really help without any code.

Comment: I just added the code of the div,, I would really apreciate any help because I'm new to web developpement and any indication would e helpful ! thanks again

Comment: why dont you use panel widget in jQM?

Comment: @Omar I'm really new to web dev if you think that it would be better with a panel widget I'll try it ! thanks ^^

Comment: Try it, if you need further assistance, let us know.

Comment: @Omar I'm trying to use panel widget I've put the new code on the question but it still not working I don't know why even if I think the code is correct... thank you !

Comment: Replace `#menu` in the function of swipe with page id `#contactF`.

Comment: `#rightpanel` with `#menu`. Make sure you go thru code when you copy/paste it.

Comment: @Omar one last question please :) should I use CSS to resize the panel or is there an other mean ?

Comment: Override `.ui-panel` and maybe `.ui-panel-inner` CSS style.